# MySQL FULLTEXT search counting occurrences

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I there a way to get the logic behind a full text search

Example table

```
+----+-------------+
| id | title       |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | Hello World |
| 2  | World World |
| 3  | Hello       |
| 4  | Hello Hello |
+----+-------------+
```

This is the query

```
SELECT `title` FROM `example` WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('World')
```

Result

```
+-------------+
| title       |
+-------------+
| World World |
| Hello World |
+-------------+
```

Now 'World World' is first since it has the 'World' Twice
Is there any way I can get somthing like this

```
+-------------+------------+-------+
| title       | appearance | score |
+-------------+------------+-------+
| World World | 2          | 1     |
| Hello World | 1          | 2     |
+-------------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try using a syntax like this, instead of attempting to count how many times the word occurs.

Notice that it uses `IN BOOLEAN MODE` that means when a `+` is before, it must occur. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
SELECT Title, MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('+World +World' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Score 
FROM `example`
WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('+World +World' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

It will generate a relevance score that you later can sort on.

If you however need to have the count, this will do the trick.

```
SELECT Title,
ROUND (
      (CHAR_LENGTH(`title`) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(`title`, "World", ""))) / CHAR_LENGTH("World")       
      ) AS appearance 
FROM `example`
WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('World')
```

Notice that it is case sensitive so could be an idea to wrap `title` with `LCASE`

Comment: ok, this gives me the score, but how can I get the number of appearances?

Comment: I like the Idea, only one problem, this will only work with one word search.

Comment: Yes its must be a exact match then. In that case you must build a function.